# How to fix Spring Boot DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: spring-boot

When I clone my project from git hub with another laptop. the console told me that below

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

The situation is very strange because the configuration with my original laptop can be work.

I already had configurated the relational properties in application.yaml like below

```
#datasource
spring:
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: 123456
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: xxxx@gmail.com
    password: 12345678
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      starttls.enable: true
      ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
#thymeleaf
  thymeleaf: cache=false

#mybatis
mybatis.type-aliases-package: com.jason.pojo
mybatis:
  configuration:
    log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl
```

and check  relational dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>jason</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jason</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the project is freshly cloned: did you run `mvn install`? Sometimes the `application.yaml` is just missing from the `target` directory.

Comment: finally. it is being work when I change application.yaml to application.yml.

Answer (score 0):

changing:

```
driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

to:

```
 driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

### Answer edited

It seem that your application not scan your properties. So try adding this to you pom.xml and unchanged if you change the **driverClassName** property I have asked to changed.

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                   <include>**/*.yaml</include>   //--> this 
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```